# Can NAT64 be accessable on the internet with an ipv6 address?

Tags: networking, ipv6

I try to grasp how NAT64 is working.
NAT64 is only used for an ipv6 host which initiates the communication with an ipv4 host.
I read that a client access the NAT64 with a prefix address 64:ff9b::/96, and the suffix will be the destinations ipv4 address. However this prefix is only allowed on a local network, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a NAT64 gateway is not to make IPv6 accessible, but to make IPv4-only hosts accessible from IPv6-only hosts. This is usually ancient legacy devices on a company's network, but NAT64 can be used along with DNS64 to allow IPv6-only devices to talk to the IPv4 Internet. Some mobile carriers do this.

Because these protocols are incompatible, the NAT64 gateway translates IPv6 to IPv4 so that the IPv6 host can reach the IPv4 host at a translated IPv6 address which begins with 64:ff9b:: and which the last four octets are the same as the four IPv4 octets. The DNS64 gateway translates an IPv4 A record to a corresponding IPv6 AAAA record containing the corresponding 64:ff9b::/96 address.

These addresses are not globally routable, and in order to use them locally, all of your routers require static routes to route 64:ff9b::/96 to the NAT64 gateway. In very simple setups where your default router is also doing NAT64/DNS64, then the default route suffices.

Comment: Does the NAT64 have a ipv4 interface with a public ipv4 address?

Comment: 64:ff9b::/96 is only the well known prefix. You can also run NAT64 on other IPv6 addresses that are globally routable. The go6lab.si offers that for testing for example

Answer (score 0):

> Does the NAT64 have a ipv4 interface with a public ipv4 address? –
> user2304458

Yes, although usually for ISP networks it is a pool of IPv4 addresses for the NAT64 gateway to use because of the 65K port limit per IPv4 address correspondingly limits the number of users served at once.

> 64:ff9b::/96 is only the well known prefix. You can also run NAT64 on
> other IPv6 addresses that are globally routable. The go6lab.si offers
> that for testing for example –  Sander Steffann

nat64.net also offers a Nat64 and DNS64 combination service for use by the public so it is Internet routable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My answer is actually two direct answers to two separate comment/questions above.  I directly quoted the text to which I am referring.  My post may not be clear to an ignorant bot such as yourself, but it is crystal clear to a human being with even a modicum of intelligence.